# Changing existing List schemas (custom ones)

Tags: list, custom-list

I have a custom list that is deployed (for a while) that has a fair few instances of that list.  I've been informed the schema.xml has a bug in it in the view/toolbar section.

So whilst I could change the schema.xml file and redeploy, I think that any list created already has that schema associated against it so my changing it on the file system will not effect it.

So am I correct ? Are these schemas already copied into each list instance (a poke about the API makes me think so)

If they are and changing the file system doesnt do anything,  has anyone SAFEFLY changed the list instances schemas (the view stuff (rendered html) not fields in a view or their order etc), does this break support if I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If changing the view schema addresses your problem, you should replace the view schema by calling SPView.SetSchema mehod and since it is an exposed method, it is supported operation.

Comment: thx, I will give that one a go in a couple of days, certainly sounds feasible for what "I think" I want to do.

Will pop back next week and let you know

Comment: Hmm struggling to find this in the API,
not in WSS3
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview_members(v=office.12).aspx#FamilyMethodsToggle

but there is a SetViewXml  in 2010

Realise I didnt specify which SharePoint, and it doesnt mean its not there, I need to check that still, just sayin.

Comment: Having checked in the API docs and reflected it on wss3 and 2010 I cannot find any method/proeprty called SetSchema, but in 2010 there is a SetViewXml.  However Im on Moss (realise I didnt mention this).  So I cannot say this is the answer as it really isnt but I did vote it up as it pointed me in a direction to research.

Comment: I thought it was sp 2010. It must be setviewxml as you found. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

The answer SPView.SetSchema was not an option for me as this is not in WSS3 (or 2010 from my quick research, please correct me if Im wrong I very well could be mistaken, but please point to the API docs).

Having changed the schema.xml (the part of it relating to the html rendering of a view ) I find that it is not (un)ghosted (whichever one that is) a chaneg to the schema.xml is replicated directly on the page.

This is probably one of those dont edit this file things because as it happens immediately ....... well you can guess the rest, however Im essentially changing a pathing problem on a rendered link that cant cause an isse, but hey extensive testing.